# Comparing root node text XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to do some comparison on the node text value.
I am facing some issues in it.

Case 1:

```
<XmlData>
    <StudentDatas NoofStudents="67">MYSCHOOL</StudentDatas>
</XmlData>
```

`/XmlData/StudentDatas/text()[.=normalize-space('MYSCHOOL')]` - it is working.

But the following case, not working:-

```
<StudentDatas>MYSCHOOLDETAILS
    <Class_A NoofStudents="67" Class_Teacher="DhanPal">
        <StudentData Category="HighClass">
            <Student Id="1010" Name="N1" BloodGroup="A+" />
            <Student Id="1011" Name="N2" BloodGroup="B+" />
            <Student Id="1012" Name="N3" BloodGroup="C+" />             
        </StudentData>          
    </Class_A>      
</StudentDatas>
```

Here i want to select the noofstudent attribute,when the root node text is matched with the given text:

```
/StudentDatas/Class_A/@NoofStudents[../text()='MYSCHOOLDETAILS']
```

But this query is not working.

May i kindly know how, where i am mistaking.

Answer (score 1):

First check the parent, then get the child's attribute:

```
/StudentDatas[normalize-space(.)='MYSCHOOLDETAILS']/Class_A/@NoofStudents
```

Demo using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "/StudentDatas[normalize-space(.)='MYSCHOOLDETAILS']/Class_A/@NoofStudents"
NoofStudents="67"
```

Answer (score 1):

alecxe has already given a good answer, I'm just adding an explanation for why your original expression did not work.

Your XPath expression:

```
/StudentDatas/Class_A/@NoofStudents[../text()='MYSCHOOLDETAILS']
```

means

> select an outermost element `StudentDatas`, select its child elements called `Class_A`, and select their attributes `NoofStudents`. But only if the parent of those attributes has at least one immediate child text node that is equal to "MYSCHOOLDETAILS".

But, as you can see, the parent of `@NoofStudents` is `Class_A` - and it does not have this text node. `StudentDatas` is the *grandparent* of this attribute. Also, the text node it contains is not equal to `MYSCHOOLDETAILS`, there is also whitespace in it.

The following path expression would have worked (still, alecxe's solution is the better way to do it)

```
/StudentDatas/Class_A/@NoofStudents[normalize-space(../../text())='MYSCHOOLDETAILS']
```

---

By the way, "datas" is not a proper English word, "data" is a plural form already.

Comment: Thanks for adding reason for adding, why "../" and thanks for highlighting that "datas"...